# AngularJS - getting asynchronous data back from a factory to use in a controller

Tags: angularjs, asynchronous, data-synchronization

The issue I'm having is that I'm trying to get data from my factory to my controller in time for the controller to access that data. Currently, when I console log out the data, I get an empty object, but if I examine the data further I get the whole "value was snapshotted, but here it is live" in Chrome.

Here's my Factory, called DataService:

```
var data = {};
var firstPillarData = {};
var secondPillarData = {};
var thirdPillarData = {};

firstPillarData.ourArray = [];
secondPillarData.ourArray = [];
thirdPillarData.ourArray = [];

function userRetrievalSuccess(response){
  console.log('userRetrievalSuccess', response.data);
  data.users = response.data;
  console.log('data.users is', data.users);
  console.log('and the data object is', data);
  for(var i = 0; i < data.users.length; i++){
    if(data.users[i].initiatives != null){
      console.log("we have initiatives for this user", data.users[i]);
      for(var j = 0; j < data.users[i].initiatives.length; j++){
        switch(data.users[i].initiatives[j].pillar){
          case 1:
            firstPillarData.ourArray.push(data.users[i].initiatives[j]);
            break;
          case 2:
            secondPillarData.ourArray.push(data.users[i].initiatives[j]);
            break;
          case 3:
            thirdPillarData.ourArray.push(data.users[i].initiatives[j]);
            break;
          default:
            break;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  data.firstPillarData = firstPillarData;
  data.secondPillarData = secondPillarData;
  data.thirdPillarData = thirdPillarData;
  console.log("our data.firstPillarData is", data.firstPillarData);
  console.log("our data.secondPillarData is", data.secondPillarData);
  console.log("our data.thirdPillarData is", data.thirdPillarData);
  return data;
}

function userRetrievalFail(){
  console.log('error retrieving users');
}

function getAllUserData(){
  $http.get('/kpi/allUsers/').then(userRetrievalSuccess, userRetrievalFail)
}
```

And here's where it's being called in my controller:

```
DataService.getAllUserData();

  var data = DataService.data;
```

I thought that using the `.then` method on the `$http.get` would handle my issue, but it clearly isn't. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your data retrieval should be inside the userRetrievalSuccess in the `.then`.
Right now you're just hoping the console.log gets called after userRetrievalSuccess gets called

Comment: @Ladmerc I'm not fully understanding what you're saying. The data is retrieved in userRetrievalSuccess when I say `data.users = response.data`, and again when I set `data.XPillar = xPillarData`... isn't it?

Comment: You're missing the fact that its' asynchronous. this means that at t0, you call the service, at t0 + a few nanoseconds, you print the data, and then, much later, at T0 + half a second, when the http response comes back, the userRetrievalSuccess function is executed and populates the data. The service should return a promise. Read http://blog.ninja-squad.com/2015/05/28/angularjs-promises/

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that adding a second promise/.then on the controller side took care of my issues. But thanks to @JB-Nizet and @Ladmerc for the help!